# Search an Array made of integers in Javascript and return new array with values

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, search

I'm trying to make a new array from an if conditional inside a for loop in JavaScript. So far the new array returns undefined when:

```
if( numbers[i] <= num)
```

I need to return all elements that are less or equal to the value of num and create a new array from them. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function search(num, numbers) {
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  var x = [];

    if( numbers[i] <= num){
    x.push(numbers[i]);}
  }
 return x;
 }

(search(14, [7, 3, 23, 9, 14, 20, 7])
```

Comment: You are doing that wrong, that you redeclare `var x = []` in each loop.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `array.filter`

```
function search(num, numbers) {
    return numbers.filter(function(n) { return n <= num });
}

search(5, [1,3,44,7,10]) //returns [1,3]
```

The core issue with your code above is that you declare `var x = []` in every iteration of the `for` loop - it's overwritten each time.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are iterating over another array "Prices" whose length may be greater than numbers array that is why you are getting undefined.

Move x=[] outside the for loop as it is getting reset for each value of for loop

"prices.length"

You can use underscore.js filter function for this

```
 bigValues = function(array){
        return _.filter(array, function(element){ 
          return element > 10; 
        });
    }
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 23 ];

var bigResult = bigValues(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no array called "prices". You should replace "prices"
   with "numbers". This is why you get undefined.
2. Move x=[] outside the for loop. Otherwise, x is going to be instantiated with an empty array every time it goes through the for loop. Your code seems to erase x's contents every time your function iterates through the loop.

```js
function search(num, numbers) {
    var x = [];
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  

    if( numbers[i] <= num){
    x.push(numbers[i]);}
  }
 return x;
 }

$('p').text(search(14, [7, 3, 23, 9, 14, 20, 7]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/3aggotnq/)